# Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined

Tags: node.js, webpack

Our application kept showing the error in the title. The problem is very likely related to Webpack 5 polyfill and after going through a couple of solutions:

1. Setting fallback + install with npm

```
fallback: {
  "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
  "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/")
}
```

2. Setting alias

```
alias: {
  "buffer": "buffer",
  "stream": "stream-browserify"
}
```

We are still seeing the dreadful error:

```
rfc6979.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at Object.4142 (rfc6979.js:3)
    at r (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.5892 (js.js:4)
    at r (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.4090 (bip32.js:5)
    at r (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.7786 (index.js:3)
    at r (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.1649 (MnemonicKey.js:50)
    at r (bootstrap:19)
```

Our setup is vanilla NodeJS + TypeScript + Webpack for multi-target: node + browser. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Answering my own question. Two things helped to resolve the issue:

1. Adding plugins section with ProviderPlugin into webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    // ...

    plugins: [
        // Work around for Buffer is undefined:
        // https://github.com/webpack/changelog-v5/issues/10
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
        }),
    ],
```

2. Also add in resolve.fallback into webpack.config.js:

```
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
        fallback: {
            "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
            "buffer": require.resolve("buffer")
        }
    },
```

Comment: I am using react-scripts 5 and this solution doesnt work for me. I tried to use `react-app-rewired` to add config-overrides.js as described. But app still doesnt find buffer

Comment: Note @tonisives that you may need to clear your cache after this change - `rm -fr node_modules/.cache`

Comment: Thanks! I managed to fix it by adding `yarn add process` Here is my full overview https://github.com/terra-money/terra.js/issues/223

Comment: hello @whileone -- this helped my use case, but by any chance do you know why this works and wasnt needed in Webpack 4? Why in Webpack 5? -- its been a nightmare fixing breaking changes

Answer (score 68):

I've tried all the answers here to resolve this issue and nothing worked for me. What did work for me was putting the following in my polyfills.ts:

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

// @ts-ignore
window.Buffer = Buffer;
```

and of course, `npm install --save buffer`

Comment: Great! This works independent of the framework used.

Comment: I was using Buffer on a single file. By just importing and setting window.Buffer on that single file fixed the problem for me without creating the polyfills.ts file.

Comment: If you use React with Vite and don't have any polyfill files - add it somewhere in the root of your app. For example in App.jsx or in main.jsx

Answer (score 41):

Everyone who came here because of **react-scripts (5.0.0)** (@whileons answer is correct, this is only the configuration for react-scripts):

First, add these dependencies to your package.json:

```
"buffer": "^6.0.3",
"process": "^0.11.10",
"stream-browserify": "^3.0.0"
"react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1" --dev
```

Update your package.json scripts.

**Before:**

```
"scripts": {
    "debug": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

**After**

```
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
```

Create a file `config-overrides.js` in the root folder (NOT under src, in the same folder like your package.json) and paste the following code inside:

```
const webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    //do stuff with the webpack config...
    config.resolve.fallback = {
        ...config.resolve.fallback,
        stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
    }
    config.resolve.extensions = [...config.resolve.extensions, ".ts", ".js"]
    config.plugins = [
        ...config.plugins,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: "process/browser",
            Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
        }),
    ]
    // console.log(config.resolve)
    // console.log(config.plugins)

    return config
}
```

Dont forget to delete node_modules and `npm install` it again.

Comment: This seems to work for me. Just wanted to point out the file name needs to be `config-overrides.js` (plural)

Comment: Very helpful, I forgot to follow the last line **Delete node_modules**. But finally deleted node_modules and installed again to get things running.

Comment: Thank you. One thing that threw me - is that I was using "yarn start" - and in your version, you have "debug" as the name of the start script - so "start" wasn't working.  I changed it to "start" and everything worked as expected. Just noting this in case others also fall down that rabbit hole.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me

```
npm install --save buffer
```

Then in the file where I was using buffer

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
```

I guess it wasn't installed, but my IDE already had type descriptions for it? Idk

Comment: Is there some way to install this globally? Like how you no longer need to `import React` to use React functionality? I don't understand how/why we no longer need to `import React` but if we could use the same tecnhnique with Buffer, I would not need to import it - and I need to import it into my node_modules/mqtt-packet/constants file to make my mqtt-react-hooks package useable.

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me is the following:

First:

```
npm install --save buffer
```

Then:

```
// webpack.config.js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
    }),
    // ..
  ]
  // ..
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error, and this is how I solved the problem.

First:

```
npm install --save buffer
```

Then:

> Added this to my `app.tsx` file.

```
window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;
```

Answer (score 4):

Additional detail for **VueJS** developers,
this answer worked and my **vue.config.js** file was like this.

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
  plugins: [
    // Work around for Buffer is undefined:
    // https://github.com/webpack/changelog-v5/issues/10
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
    })
  
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    fallback: {
      "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      "buffer": require.resolve("buffer")
    }
  },
 }
})
```

I deleted my node_modules folder and ran `npm install` again.

Comment: TypeError: defineConfig is not a function

Comment: What webpack, vue, and npm versions are you using? vue 3 with webpack 5.88.2 and npm 9.8.1 causes a TypeError in `webpack\lib\compilation.js\`?

Answer (score 3):

You could also just install the following library: https://github.com/feross/buffer

`yarn add buffer`

Answer (score 2):

While everyone is suggesting to install polyfill, there is a native way in NodeJS to do this, per their [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/buffer.html#class-buffer)

```
import { Buffer } from 'node:buffer'
```

If you are using this in NodeJs, including Webpack, and not in the browser, this is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a bug when I tried to use TonWebSDK with create-react-app and found a fix for that.

After project setup with `npx create-react-app my-app` I imported `tonweb from 'tonweb'` but faced an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined`.

I run `npm run eject` in order to modify the webpack config. I added Buffer support to the `plugins` of webpack with next lines:

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        })
```

And this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading react-scripts to 4.0.3 worked https://github.com/terra-money/terra.js/issues/223.
It may not be the optimal solution, but it was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: Check answer of @parliament [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71953677/5230243)

Comment: That really isn't a solution, as there are more and more security issues with the dependencies pulled in by CRA 4.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is third-party plugin that provides all node.js polyfills (not just Buffer) out of the box:
`node-polyfill-webpack-plugin`.

It brings all polyfills as its own dependancies, so you should use
`excludeAliases` config property to define what polyfills you do not want to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Install `casbin.js@^1.0.1` instead of `casbin`.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS minimizer in Webpack 5 is more strict about what is allowed in the CSS files.  You likely have a misplaced `/` somewhere in your CSS.

For instance, it does not like `//` comments:
`// This will break`

Also, check for slashes in any className paths, e.g.:
`.myDiv/otherDiv`

Removing these will solve your problem and allow you to keep your optimized CSS.  Replace any comments using the `/* */` syntax.  Also check to make sure those are well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Craco, this is the way to format the code in `craco.config.js` to resolve the Buffer is not defined:

```js
//plugin to avoid Buffer is not defined
webpackConfig.plugins.push(
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     process: 'process/browser',
  }),
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
  })
);
```