# Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined at varintEncode (util.js:33:1) - due do this my application is crashing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Our application is showing this error in the console. Please help if anybody knows about it.

Error-

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at varintEncode (util.js:33:1)
    at ./node_modules/multicodec/src/varint-table.js (varint-table.js:11:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/multicodec/src/index.js (index.js:16:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/content-hash/src/index.js (index.js:19:1)[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68707553/uncaught-referenceerror-buffer-is-not-defined

Answer (score -1):

I succeed to solve the problem by following those steps:

1. Uninstall Webpack 5: npm uninstall webpack
2. delete package-lock.json
3. Go to package.json and change from "React-scripts": "5.0.0" to "React-scripts": "4.0.3",
4. install webpack 4: npm install webpack@4.44.2
5. npm install
6. npm run start

I hope it helps, if yes don't hesitate to upvote ;)