# Download and save MJPEG with http command (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fetch, hikvision

I'm using a hikvision IP camera that streams 30 MJPEG images per second to a certain http url and Javascript Reactjs with nodejs and express as backend.

Also hikvision provides a url to snap the camera image when you open the link.
Example link:

```
http://192.168.0.109/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/1/picture
```

I want to download that image and store it as a local file on my computer, I know how to store it but I haven't been able to download the image programatically.

I followed the next guide to get those API endpoints (stream and snapshot):
[HIKVISION TUTORIAL](https://www.hikvision.com/content/dam/hikvision/en/support/download/how-to/ipc/How%20to%20Get%20IPC%20MJPEG%20Stream%20via%20HTTP%20Commands.pdf)

My question is, how do I fetch or download that image ?

I have tried with fetch without success.

Not sure but as long as I understand it requires a basic digest authorization and I haven't find how to fetch with digest auth. If I open the link directly on my browser, a pop up prompts and ask me for my username and password.

Everytime I try to fetch the response is :

```
GET http://192.168.0.109/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/1/picture net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)
```

There is also some parameters to this API command on documentation that includes a json format that I have tried without success:

[image: Hik documentation image]

Also, as you can see on HIKVISION TUTORIAL there is an url to get the stream, I'm able to reproduce that MJPEG stream on front-end with the next code with no issues:

```
<img
                width={"90%"}
                height={"60%"}
                alt="stream"
                src={"http://192.168.0.109/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/102/httpPreview"}
                id="cam1"
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

> `net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)`

Based on the error you presented, I suspect that you have set a username/password.

The [documentation](https://www.hikvision.com/content/dam/hikvision/en/support/download/how-to/ipc/How%20to%20Get%20IPC%20MJPEG%20Stream%20via%20HTTP%20Commands.pdf) (that you linked to in your question) explains that if you have set a username/password, then you need to use `Basic` auth:

```
http://<username>:<password>@<IP address of IPC>:<HTTP
port>/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/1/picture
```

So, if the local IP address that you're using is `192.168.0.109`, then the URL format would be:

```
http://<username>:<password>@192.168.0.109/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/1/picture
```

and `<username>` and `<password>` would be your actual username and password.

---

Note that this URL format is deprecated in many environments. You can send the auth data in the request headers instead:

```js
function setBasicAuthHeader (headers, username, password) {
  // In Node:
  const encoded = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`).toString('base64');

  // In a browser/deno:
  // const encoded = window.btoa(`${username}:${password}`);

  headers.set('Authorization', `Basic ${encoded}`);
}

const username = 'me';
const password = 'secret';

const headers = new Headers();
setBasicAuthHeader(headers, username, password));

// Use headers in your request...
```

Comment: Am I supposed to run this code in front or backend? I have tried this before, but I get the next error: ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined.......... Not sure how to define it, right now running on frontend react 18.2.0, with react-scripts 5.0.1

Comment: I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205013/9749951 to solve the Bufffer issue, but still getting 401 Unauthorized

Comment: @LuisQuiroga For a browser environment, see commented lines 5–6 in the last code snippet.