# Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined even after adding the webpack plugin for buffer

Tags: reactjs, webpack, buffer, babel-polyfill

I followed the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68723223/14758033
added the plugin inside the module.exports object of react-scripts webpack config

and added fallback in my webpack.config.js of react-scripts

```
fallback:{
    "buffer": require.resolve("buffer"),
    "util": require.resolve("util/"),
    "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
    "assert": require.resolve("assert/") 
  },
```

still the error persists . Can anyone tell me how to fix it ? Trying to work with react-pdf-renderer . Added the polyfill but buffer undefined persists.

Buffer undefined error

[image: 2]

Comment: What's the error? Provide the details in your question